# Arraylist sorting method isn't returning what it's supposed to. Probably a logical error

Tags: java, arraylist, return, logic, nested-for-loop

I have a method that's supposed to go through an ArrayList of words and put them in order alphabetically using .compareTo().
This is the testing text in a txt document: environment,city,character,road,salad,banner,bed,thank,attachment,medium,record,speech,pause.
Instead of returning a sorted list it just returns that list.

**This is the method in a class called ListSorter**

```
public ArrayList<String> sortWords(ArrayList<String> wordList) { // changed static void
    // TO DO #1: Sort the words in wordList in alphabetical order.
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int outter = 0; outter<wordList.size(); outter ++){ // takes 1 word in the list at a time
      for(int inner = 0; inner<wordList.size(); inner ++){ // compares it to all the other words in the list
         if((wordList.get(outter)).compareTo(wordList.get(inner)) ==0 ){ 
        // return i;
           newList.add(inner,wordList.get(outter));// adds current word to index of the inner loop
       }// end of if
   } // end of inner
    }// end outter
       return newList;
```

**This is what is currently in MyConsole**

```
    ArrayList<String> wordList = FileReader.getStringData("words.txt");
ListSorter newList = new ListSorter();
   // newList.setTextList(wordList);
    // TO DO #2: Call the sortWords() method and print the updated list.
System.out.print(newList.sortWords(wordList));
```

Comment: This algorithm doesn't make sense. Your if condition is only true, if the words are equal. thus only if inner == outer you add an element to the new list. At that at the same index as before. This obviously creates the same list as before. What sorting algorithm are you trying to archieve?

Answer (score 0):

Might be A **little late** to answer it

and might **not be the most efficient** way to sort it

but it **does the work**

```
    for(int i=65;i<=90;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<wordList.size();j++)
        {
            if( ((int) wordList.get(j).toUpperCase().charAt(0)) == i )
            {
                newList.add(wordList(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return newList;
```

it adds all the words to the newList starting with **a and continues till z** after comparing it with every words starting alphabet **;)**